# EMAIL in Compute Engine

Tags: email, configuration, google-cloud-platform, gmail

First of all, I apologize for my ignorance (and my English), but let me explain my problem:
I read that GCloud does not allow sending emails and they suggest to use Sendgrid, Mailjet etc.
I chose Mailjet and it works fine. I use "contacto@appreciate.com.ar" as a sender email account. 
The problem is I don't know where to configure an email in case someone want to reply. 
Do I have to use a gmail sender instead of "contacto@appreciate.com.ar" or there is a way to configure a receiver account in GCloud?

Thanks in advance!
Julieta

Comment: Inbound and outbound email can be (and frequently are) handled by separate systems. You can use Gmail to receive emails (via their G Suite offering), and Mailjet to send them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will investigate Gsuite then!

Answer (score -1):

I found a great answer to your question in the following [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749187/how-to-receive-email-on-google-compute-engine).

Basically, You can still run a mail server which just receives emails. In other words, you only have to open up listening ports using [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) as by default GCE firewall blocks all incoming traffic.